# Unable to initialize RegisteredServersStore object in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, module, registration, dbatools

I am using Powershell to try to create an object of type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.RegisteredServersStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.registeredservers.registeredserversstore?view=sql-smo-160). According to the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.registeredservers.registeredserversstore.-ctor?view=sql-smo-160#microsoft-sqlserver-management-registeredservers-registeredserversstore-ctor(microsoft-sqlserver-management-common-serverconnection)), it ought to be able to be created using a Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection object as a parameter. With that in mind, I am trying to run the following code:

```
$ServerConnection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection('ServerName')
$ServerConnection
$store = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.RegisteredServersStore($ServerConnection)
```

The assignment for `$ServerConnection` is successful and printing the object's information verifies that. However, the assignment for `$store` gives this error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "RegisteredServersStore" and the argument count: "1".
At line:4 char:10
+ $store = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers. ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I am confused as to why the constructor for this class is throwing that error when the documentation suggests that it should work with that parameter.

I have tried it without the parameter and it does initialize in that case; I was hoping perhaps there was a method to instantiate a connection to the server, but I don't see anything like that. I am using Powershell 5.1.17763.4720 and the SqlServer module is on version 22.1.1.

For the record, this came about through attempting to use the dbatools function [Add-DbaRegServer](https://docs.dbatools.io/Add-DbaRegServer), which then calls a couple of other dbatools functions, including [Get-DbaRegServerStore](https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools/blob/master/public/Get-DbaRegServerStore.ps1), of which line 63 is the problematic one:

```
$store = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.RegisteredServersStore($server.ConnectionContext)
```

My code above is an attempt at recreating this in a controlled environment. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: So which version of SSMS do you have installed? Did you notice in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.registeredservers.registeredserversstore.-ctor#microsoft-sqlserver-management-registeredservers-registeredserversstore-ctor#microsoft-sqlserver-management-common-serverconnection) that it's only applicable to Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects versions 150.18208.0 and 160.2004021.0 (which is SSMS 18.4 and 18.5 specifically)?

Comment: How can I check the version of Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects? Strangely enough, after I closed and reopened ISE, I ran the dbatools command and it worked just fine. I've been unable to replicate the issue since then, so I'm not sure what happened. My best guess is that something earlier in the script loaded an earlier version of the package that dbatools was forced into using. I'll keep experimenting and  try to get that error again, but it's definitely puzzling me.